Docker not building due to ODBC missing sqlext.h
Trying to build a Docker image from the latest 8.3-apache.
The build systematically crashes because of a missing file while attempting to build PHP ODBC deps from the command "RUN docker-php-ext-install odbc".
ODBC is required in a little PHP script that I use to retrieve data from a Microsoft SQL Server. Is there any alternative that I can use to that, which does not require the ODBC PHP extension?
The precise error message is :
113.9 configure: error: ODBC header file '/usr/local/incl/sqlext.h' not found!
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install     pdo     pdo_mysql     mysqli     intl     zip     gd     opcache     xsl     gd     odbc" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Here is my full Dockerfile if that may help:
FROM php:8.3-apache

# Apache configuration
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    gpg \
    curl \
    wget \
    build-essential \
    gnupg2 \
    ca-certificates \
    libapache2-mod-fcgid \
    locales coreutils apt-utils git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . .

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /var/www/html

# Install PHP dependencies and optimize
RUN composer install --no-dev --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader \
    && composer dump-autoload --optimize \
    && composer dump-env prod

# Install Microsoft ODBC driver and SQLSRV extension
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/12/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18

# Install the SQLSRV and PDO_SQLSRV PHP extensions
RUN pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv \
    && docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

# Install MS SQL client dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y msodbcsql18

# SQLSRV and PDO_SQLSRV extensions configuration
RUN echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sqlsrv.ini
RUN echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo-sqlsrv.ini
RUN echo "extension=odbc.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/odbc.ini

# PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo \
    pdo_mysql \
    mysqli \
    intl \
    zip \
    gd \
    opcache \
    xsl \
    gd \
    odbc

# Set permissions for the application files
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

# Configure PHP OPcache
RUN { \
    echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
    echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
    echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
    echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=0'; \
    echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
    echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
} > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini

# Copy Apache VirtualHost configuration
COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

EXPOSE 80

# Run Apache in the foreground
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]```


I'm guessing you probably want to run apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 before pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv.

And the opposite for composer install -- if your composer.json (which I assuming you're mounting into the container) requires pdo_sqlsrv then your composer install will fail because you're running that before the module is installed.

Er wait a sec.. you're installing msodbcsql18 twice...
